# Conditional Formatting a cell which contains already a formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, automation

I have a column full of this kind of formula here

```
=IF(O(AH4="";AI4="";AJ4="";AK4="");"";SUM(SUM(24;-AI4);AJ4))
```

I know i can use SUMIF, but this is not the point of my question. Basically, this function will give me a null value ("") or a time value (hh:mm). Then, if this time value is below 8:00 AM i want the cell to be colored in Red and the text i want it to be Bold.

I really don't understand why this code here don't work if it's put n the HOME > CONDITIONAL FORMATTING > ADD NEW RULE > USE A FORMULA TO DETERMINE WHICH CELLS TO FORMAT

```
=$AE4<TIME(8;0;0)
```

The cell AE4 is the first cell of the column i mentioned before, full of the first formula.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use this if you do not want blanks to be highlighted:

```
=AND(AE4<TIME(8,0,0),NOT(ISBLANK(AE4)))
```

use this if you want also blanks to be highlighted:

```
=AE4<TIME(8,0,0)
```

use any of these. then check the formula at edit so there will be no unwanted $ signs.
then be sure that at conditinal formatting rules, this is applied to the whole AE column

Comment: It doesn't work. I think im doing something wrong at the beginning then ...

Comment: I understood the problem and now it works fine !!! Thank you so much